# Why do hillshades from Image analysis look much better than the hilshade tool in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, hillshade, arcgis-10.7

I have been hoping to make my workflow a little more automated, but the hillshades that result from the hillshade tool just don't do it since they have a static look to them. I've tried to play around with the settings but nothing seems to work. I have added pictures from both methods, the only setting changed from default is setting a z-factor of 4.

This is the result from the image analysis method
[image: DEM from the image analysis method]
These are the parameters from the image analysis
[image]

This is the result from the hillshade tool
[image: DEM from the hillshade tool]

These are the parameters from the hillshade tool. I did not change any of the environment settings.
[image]

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the **exact** settings used, and which picture uses which parameters.

Comment: In the layer properties for each, what's the display resampling set to?  Are they the same?  The "worse" hillshade just looks like nearest-neighbor to me

Comment: I agree with mikewatt.  Perhaps the default image analysis uses Bilinear or Cubic Convolution resampling (which is correct for this type of data), while the Hillshade tool uses Nearest Neighbor (incorrect).  Each tool's Environment settings may offer different resampling methods.

Comment: The display resampling was set to nearest neighbour for both of them. I wasn't able to find the sampling methods in the environment settings, but changing the method in the properties to bilinear or cubic didn't change it. I also tried removing compression with no luck.